# Knockout MVC Html.RadioButton

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I am trying to use this example:

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: displayMessage" /> Display message</label>
    <div data-bind="if: displayMessage">Here is a message. Astonishing.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        displayMessage: ko.observable(false)
    });
</script>
```

My question is how can display the message if the following RadioButton is checked.

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("answer", qm.DynamicQuestions[index].Answer_A, (qm.LearnerAnswers[index] == qm.DynamicQuestions[index].Answer_A))%><%= Html.Encode( qm.DynamicQuestions[index].Answer_A) %>
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: The problem is that the top code example is html/javascript and the bottom code example is ASP.net MVC server code that gets converted to html when it is sent to the browser.  What you need to do is get the HTML that is sent to the browser and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/ktcY5/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: questions">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: availableAnswers">
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: value, checked: checked, attr: {name: $parent.id }" />
                    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


var questions = [{
    id: 'ID1',
    description: ko.observable('Should I answer this?'),
    availableAnswers: [{
        value: 'Yes',
        checked: ko.observable('Yes')
    }, {
        value: 'No',
        checked: ko.observable(false)
    }]
},{
    id: 'ID2',
 description: ko.observable('How about answering this?'),
    availableAnswers: [{
        value: 'Yes',
        checked: ko.observable()
    }, {
        value: 'No',
        checked: ko.observable('No')
    }]
}];

var vm = {
    questions: questions,

}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan, good example; however I am trying to convert my existing html.Radiobutton.  I found this example http://knockoutmvc.com/ControlTypes, unfortuntaley it is Razor, now I am trying to figure out how to use it for aspx.